# How to prevent test db from being overwriten by rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to keep rspec from trying to recreate the test database on each test iteration?    I am developing a reporting app and I want to test against the legacy read only data.

Rails 3.1.1 
rspec-rails 2.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd answer my own question in case it can help someone else. 
I have given up trying to get rspec to use legacy, read only data, for testing.  It appears this is "swimming against the tide" and is probably not considered to be the "Rails Way".  I suppose it would violate the theory that your tests should not be dependent on external data.
So I am using a sqllite db and creating data in the tests.